# Connecting from ArcGIS Desktop to virtual machine's ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, virtual-machine

I have made an OpenVPN connection to an "inner network", my school's private network. I can use the remote desktop application after the connection, so it's surely work. The ArcGIS Server is in a virtual machine, in a Windows Server 2008 R2.

The Server's version is 10.1 (I did not have refreshed that yet), and the ArcGIS Desktop version is 10.2. The Desktop application is installed on my computer. I have added myself as administrator on the ArcGIS Server Manager.

How should I connect to the server (i.e. add that GIS server to the ArcCatalog)?

I have written in the URL:

```
http://nameofthecomputerwithArcGISServer:6080/arcgis
```

But it says it cannot connect to the server.

Comment: A diagram would go a long way toward explaining the problem.  I can't tell what network link you're attempting, but it sounds like you're missing DNS.

Comment: A sketch in Paint with boxes for each host (labelled with a name), lines representing network links, and a description of the task with respect to the hostnames labelled on the diagram would be far more useful than English (or Hungarian) alone.  Identifying which hosts have firewalls configured would also help.

Comment: I don't know where is firewall or which hosts have firewalls. But if there won't be any solution I will ask the root of the school server about that.

Comment: That's the point of the diagram -- to identify possible obstructions.  If you don't know how you want the packets passed, it's unlikely that you'll get connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not installed the webadapter the url you want to use depends on what connection you are trying to create in catalog.
If you are creating a connection for publishing you want to create an admin or publishing connection in the ArcGIS servers section in catalog. my connection is like
http://domainname.com:6080/arcgis/admin